# Parsing a specific xml tag in c# and putting it in a value

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have a task to parse a XML file and put specific tags in variables in c# programming language.

The XML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item  name="whatever">
  <params name="items">
    <param name="item1">
      <comm>30313</comm>
    </param>
    <param name="item2">
      <comm>30313</comm>
    </param>
    <param name="item3">
      <comm>30313</comm>
    </param>
    <param name="item3">
      <comm>30313</comm>
    </param>
  </params>
</item>
```

So now my task to do is when a button is pressed i need to parse the value `<comm>30313</comm>` from the tag  `<param name="item3">` and put it in a string value and then if i press another button save it in the same tag back in xml.

Comment: Okay, so have you done *any* research into parsing an XML document and looking for a specific element yet? I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML.

Comment: [What have you tried so far that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: It the last item suppose to be item4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is using LINQ to XML, as Jon Skeet suggested you investigate.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"path\to\file.xml");

var item3Comm = doc.Descendants("param")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "item3")
    .Elements("comm")
    .Single();

var item3CommText = item3Comm.Value;

item3Comm.Value = "new value"

doc.Save(@"path\to\file.xml");
```

Comment: Ok so how can i now set a textbox Text with the value of  item3CommText?

Comment: `textBox.Text = item3CommText`? If you can't work it out, I'd suggest you do some research, try and solve it, and ask another question if you have a problem.

Comment: In your code you wrote i get this error: operator == cannot be applied to operands of type XAttribute and string why?

Comment: @AndrejMaleckar fixed, sorry - small mistake, I left a cast out.

Comment: now i get : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll   for this exact section why??

Comment: What's the message? Note you will get an exception for the *exact* XML in the question because you have two elements with the `item3` attribute (I assumed this was a typo). If you change `Single` to `First`, you would get the first of the matched elements.

Comment: It says sequence contains no elements. Yeah i know my xml is a lill bit different:  <param name="C01">
      <comm>30313</comm>
      <command>INA</command>
      <factor>5</factor>
      <index>2</index>
      <meter>0</meter>
      <player>1023</player>
      <meterstring>ml_BET</meterstring>
    </param>
and i wrote this:             var item3Comm = doc.Descendants("param")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "item3")
    .Elements("comm")
    .Single();

Comment: You don't have any `param` elements with `name="item3"`, so it's not surprising none are found.

Comment: Yeah i changed to name = "C01" and still the same message

Comment: Also tried this : var krneki = doc.XPathSelectElement("//param[@name='C01']/player/text()");     but yet no element found hmm

Comment: I really would avoid XPath. The code will work, I'd suggest you provide a [fiddle](http://www.dotnetfiddle.com) that shows it doesn't, then it may become more obvious what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @AndrejMaleckar For example, taking the XML in your comment, [it works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/05T2BD).